# Can Cloudflare cache HTML for anonymous users but not logged in users?

Tags: cloudflare

We have a website with anonymous user content generally static (updated once every hour), and content for logged in users different for every user, updated frequently.

Is it possible to configure cloudflare so that HTML is cached for anonymous users but not logged in users, given the same URL for both?

Are there any cache headers we can set that are relevant?

Comment: How have you got on with this? Any better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have been struggling with the same scenario, and as far as i seen there's no way,
In cloudflare you can set up Page Rules but those will only look at the URL itself.

So the only solution i see would be having diferent URL's (some extra parameter or maybe a subdomain) for each kind of users, then you'll easily set up the rules to manually force the cache expiration time

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would work, but the only way I can think of doing this as a  possibility is via HTTP/HTTPS as you can use this in the CloudFlare Page Rules.

So if you set the WordPress FORCE_SSL_ADMIN constant to true, and then were to redirect all the logged in user URL requests to the HTTPS schema of the page, this might do the trick and thus make it possible to bypass the CloudFlare cache?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless you are on the Enterprise plan level.

https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/

Answer (score -3):

A solution from [here](http://www.andrews.com/cloudflare-tip-cache-everything-except-member-only-info/)

Add a private cache control to the page header:

```
//recommended by cloudflare for logged in users
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
header(‘Cache-Control: private, max-age=3600’);
}
```

Comment: This won't prevent logged in users being served the cached "logged out" version of the site.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. [Cloudflare says](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-CloudFlare-What-to-Cache-) it will respect meta tags requesting no cache, therefore simply add those tags to the header section of the page for logged in users.

Example (using smarty)

```
{if $loggedin}
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
{/if}
```

(using PHP)

```
if($loggedin)
  {
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"no-cache\" />";
  }
```

Comment: This won't prevent logged in users being served the cached "logged out" version of the site.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer, I used Cloudflare for all my sites, and I have yet to be sent a logged out page when I'm logged in. I have over 50 sites.

Comment: Then maybe the pages are not cached at all? Did you turn on the "Cache Everything" rule? Your solution prevents Cloudflare from caching pages as seen by logged-in users and doesn't prevent caching pages as seen by logged-out users. I think we agree about this part. So what happens when a user's client asks for a page that is in Cloudflare cache (no matter if the user is logged in or not - Cloudflare has no knowledge about that)? They will get the version straight from the cache. Which in your case is the logged-out version. Your server is not hit in such case at all.

Comment: I have it on the standard caching mode. I caches just fine, but serves live pages for anyone logged in. That's how CloudFlare works. It respects the header codes when asked to not cache. When you make a request, the header is fetched first. The header is generated by script, and if you're logged in (and using the code above) then CloudFlare will see that it needs to fetch a fresh page for you. If there's no caching instructions in the header, then it will serve a cached page and it won't cache pages where the header says to not cache, so it will fetch the last cachable page.

Comment: You are mistaken. CloudFlare does not hit the server for the requests that it cached. It serves them straight from the cache. By default Cloudflare only caches static files [listed here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-Cloudflare-cache-for-static-content-). Since you did you turn on the "Cache Everything" rule, your pages are just not cached - just the images, CSS, JS, and other static things.

Comment: See also: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168216--Does-Cloudflare-cache-HTML-content-

Comment: I've just asked a similar question here:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/356303/using-cloudflare-caching-on-wordpress-with-front-end-user-logins  - Did anyone figure this out conclusively?